# Node js and mongo db bug

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a program that simulates an exchange and seems to work well especially when I set one stop loss or take profit. However, when there are multiple occurrences it just executes one. I can't seem to figure it out. This also happens for an abstraction I call short interest. Mongo seems to create two instances when I save and this is a bit problematic. I know the code is over the place now but I intend to get it working then start optimizing. Here are the codes that executes the above abstractions:

```
    tradeIdIndex = results.history[results.history.length - 1]._id;
        if(req.body.typeofTrade == 'short'){
            results.shortInterest.push({
                time : Date(),
                price : req.body.price,
                tradeId : tradeIdIndex,
                typeofTrade : req.body.typeofTrade,
                quantity : req.body.quantity,
                userId : req.body.userId
            })
            results.save();
        }
```

This saves the shortInterest that I wish to expunge later if some conditions are met. If the conditions for expunging the shortInterest, the takeProfit and stopLosses are met, the below code is called which is actually just a snippet of the function. It executes as I expect it to.

```
if(tradeId){
        console.log("I am checking the sell and cover to remove the respective open trades");
        for(var i = userData.openTrades.length -1; i >= 0; i--){
            if(userData.openTrades[i].celebrity == self.req.celebrityName && userData.openTrades[i].typeofTrade == typeofTrade && userData.openTrades[i].tradeId == tradeId){
                console.log(userData.openTrades[i]);
                userData.openTrades.splice(i, 1);

                userData.save();
            }
        };
        }
```

It returns control to the below code which actually called it to continue execution.

```
case "short" :
        checkSellandCover(userData, 'short', self, req.tradeId);
        removeStops(self.celebrity, userId, 'cover', req.tradeId);
        removeTakeProfits(self.celebrity, userId, 'cover', req.tradeId);
        removeShortInterest(self.celebrity, userId, 'short', req.tradeId);
        userData.save();

        if(self.celebrity.ask > req.shortPrice){
           value = parseFloat(self.celebrity.ask) * parseFloat(req.quantity) - parseFloat(req.shortPrice) * parseFloat(req.quantity);

           userData.accountValue = parseFloat(userData.accountValue) - value + parseFloat(req.shortPrice) * parseFloat(req.quantity);
           userData.save();
          } else {
                  value = 2 * parseFloat(req.shortPrice) * parseFloat(req.quantity) - parseFloat(self.celebrity.ask) * parseFloat(req.quantity);
                  userData.accountValue = userData.accountValue + value;
                  userData.save();
          }
          break;
```

As stated my problems and questions are:

1) Why does mongo save my data twice.
2) If I have more than one stop loss or take profits the above code does not execute appropriately. Same with the short interest because it is saved twice. Now that I have asked this question, I am beginning to think it is because I am performing database operations and the database search might still be executing when the results.save() instruction is executed.

Comment: It saves twice because you wrote `userData.save();` twice...

Comment: Thanks my bad. I scratch that off. Such a stupid mistake to make.